# Alternative to FindFirstVolumeMountPoint which doesn't require admin rights?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mount-point, volumes, reparsepoint

Is there an alternative to `FindFirstVolumeMountPoint` (and friends) that won't fail if the user running the code is not admin?

I was thinking about `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices` for one, but when I look at it, it wouldn't give me any information.

Comment: I suppose you could search the directory tree yourself, skipping over any directories you don't have permission to access.  It would be slow though.

Comment: Very slow, yes. And given that the mount manager knows about the mount points (as opposed to directory junctions) it should be possible, one would expect.